# Prevent deletion of specific icons from dock

Tags: dock

I regularly accidentally drag the Downloads folder from the dock to trash when trying to delete a recently downloaded file, removing it from he dock.

Is there any way to disable dragging and deleting icons from the dock? An equivalent of locking a file but for individual dock icons?

I don't want to lock the entire dock, just specific icons.

Comment: There is no way to lock specific icons in the Dock. You can lock all icons using the method in [daniil-manokhin's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/345918/1860).

Comment: I'm curious as to how you manage that, as all that happens for me if I drag the Downloads Dock Tile off of the Dock or over to the Trash Dock Tile, it simply removes the Downloads Dock Tile if I let go of it, **not** into the Trash. What version of macOS are you running and is it actually putting the Downloads Dock Tile or the Downloads folder into the Trash?

Comment: It doesn't end up in Trash. It gets removed from the dock, as you describe. Updated question to clarify.

Comment: I wonder if it would be possible to write a tweak that supports dragging the topmost item (the most recent one, in the usual configuration) instead of the whole stack. That would be sooo convenient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to lock specific icons.

To lock all the icons go to Terminal and type:

```
defaults write com.apple.Dock contents-immutable -bool yes
```

Press enter then type:

```
killall Dock
```

Comment: This is not what the OP needs, unfortunately, and its mentioned at the very end of the question.

Comment: @IconDaemon I said it is not possible

Comment: I know. The OP mentions in the question itself that the solution you provided will not work, thus your answer is not really an answer that will work.

Comment: It wasn't what I needed, but it does answer the question (you can't do what I want) and provides the closest option (lock all icons) so a good answer and didn't deserve a down vote.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has not implemented support for this in the Dock, only the all-or-nothing approach is available.